# How do I call a method shared by classes without casting out of the Object superclass first in Java

Tags: java, class, object, casting

I have multiple different classes (`Star`, `Planet`, `Moon`) each with different draw methods, and I would like to be able to call their respective `draw()` methods with one call, without having to cast them 3 different times.

```
Object solarObject = solarObjects.get(i);

if (solarObject.getClass() == Star.class)   ((Star)   solarObject).draw(system);
if (solarObject.getClass() == Planet.class) ((Planet) solarObject).draw(system);
if (solarObject.getClass() == Moon.class)   ((Moon)   solarObject).draw(system);
```

What I wanted to work was this

```
Object solarObject = solarObjects.get(i);

solarObject.draw(system);
```

A different attempt I made was this

```
solarObject.getClass().cast(solarObject).draw(system);
```

but it gave the error `The method draw is undefined for the type`

Is there any way to achieve this sort of behaviour in Java?

Comment: Yes, you would make them all either subclasses of a common superclass, or implement the same interface. (It's hard to tell which would be more appropriate in this case.) Basically I suggest you read up on inheritance and interfaces.

Comment: `solarObject.getClass() == Star.class` You know about instanceof operator, right? `solarObject instanceof Star`? It's not identical, but for your purposes almost certainly accomplishes the same task. Has the benefit of not throwing if solarObject is null, and is more expressive .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achive the same job with uncluttered typecasting, you make the classes a subclass of a common abstract/concret superclass, or have them implement a common interface (whichever fits your project design). This way, you can store whichever subclass object to that interface and call the 'draw()' method on it (regardless of the type of object, since they all implement the same interface).

Code:

```
public interface CelestialBody {
    void draw();
}

public class Star implements CelestialBody{
    public void draw(){}
}

public class Planet implements CelestialBody{
    public void draw(){}
}
```

Demo:

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CelestialBody solarObject1 = new Star();
        CelestialBody solarObject2 = new Planet();
        if (solarObject1 instanceof CelestialBody)
            solarObject1.draw();
        if (solarObject2 instanceof CelestialBody)
            solarObject2.draw();
    }
}
```

Notice that when accepting an unknown object, we use the ['instanceof' operator](https://www.javatpoint.com/downcasting-with-instanceof-operator) before referencing it (this is to insure that the inputted object is in fact of type 'CelestialBody').

This type of problem is solved through [Inheritance](https://www.javatpoint.com/inheritance-in-java). I would encourage you to read more about it.

Comment: Worth noting that with instanceof pattern matching (Java 16+) you can avoid the explicit cast to CelestialBody: https://openjdk.org/jeps/394

Comment: Thanks! What if I don't want an implementation for one of the interfaced methods in one of the classes that implements it?

Comment: @APerson You have two choices: You either make the subclass that doesn't implement all the interface method(s) abstract. Or, you make the CelestialBody an abstract class instead of an interface (also the 'draw()' method inside of it has to be abstract). This way, any subclass that implements the 'draw()' method gets to be concret, and any subclass that doesn't has to be abstract.